# How to dynamically append a string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to append the value selected from a dropdown menu to an element in the body.
To double check that the dropdown returns any values, I used the jquery to change the background color of the page, which works. However, I am not able to conditionally display the color name `after()` the `<p></p>` element:

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7765fvjf/

```js
$('#dropdlist').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function()  {
var $color = $('#dropdlist :selected').text();
$('body').css('background', $color);
var $colorName = $('.colorName');
var newColor = ("<p class='colorLabel'>" + $color + "</p>");
var $colorLabel= $('.colorName',$newColor);

if (!$colorLabel[0]) $colorName.after(newColor);
else $colorName.replaceWith(newColor)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdlist'>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<p id='tt' class='colorName'>
The background color is:
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems more useful to have the colorLabel `span` present from the start -- with an `id` -- and only update *its* contents, not the contents of the surrounding `p` which only complicates things.

Secondly, using the `change` event is more appropriate.

Finally, with `trigger()` you can launch the function upon page load as well:

```js
$('#dropdlist').on('change', function()  {
  var $color = $('#dropdlist :selected').text();
  $('body').css('background', $color);
  $("#colorLabel").text($color);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdlist'>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<p id='tt' class='colorName'>
The background color is: <span id="colorLabel"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a syntax error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $newColor is not defined`.

Updated JS code to:

```
$('#dropdlist').on('change', function()  {
  var $color = $('#dropdlist :selected').text();
  $('body').css('background', $color);
  var htmlTarget = $('.colorName span');
  var newColor = ("<p class='colorLabel'>" + $color + "</p>");
  var $colorLabel= $('.colorName',newColor);

  htmlTarget.html(newColor);
  //else $colorName.replaceWith(newColor);
});
```

This works. See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7765fvjf/6/

Comment: Sorry my question was probably unclear, I was trying to append/replace the value as the if statement would suggest

Comment: Edited to replace existing string rather than append.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like so, add a "color" span and change it's content dynamically each time the user select a new color.

```js
$('#dropdlist').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function()  {
  var $color = $('#dropdlist :selected').text();
  $('body').css('background', $color);
  // change the text of ".color" span
  $(".color").html($color);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdlist'>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<p id='tt' class='colorName'>
The background color is: <span class="color"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Just provide an id to the paragraph.

**HTML :**

```
<select id="dropdlist">
  <option value="volvo">green</option>
  <option value="saab">yellow</option>
  <option value="mercedes">blue</option>
</select>
<p id="para"></p>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$('#dropdlist').on('change', function() {
  var $color = $('#dropdlist :selected').text();
  $('body').css('background', $color);
  var $colorName = $('.colorName');
  $('#para').html('The background color is ' + $color)
});
```

**JSFiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/weqo1y30/